# Pass multiple values in Syabse

Tags: sql, parameters, ssrs-2012, sap-ase

I am back again with a small problem. Hope i get something here.

I am working on a report, SQL Server Reporting Services 2012 and Database is Sybase ASE.
One of my report parameter can have multiple values. Let's name the parameter as @Fruit. It can have multiple values. So if the user selects Apple and Mango from the list, it should pass to the query at backend.

The parameter gives the values as : Apple,Mango
Now i need to pass it to the query in the below way.

```
SELECT 
COLUMN1,
COLUMN2,
COLUMN3
FROM DBO.TABLE_NAME
WHERE COLUMN2 IN ('Apple','Mango')
```

Problem: I am able to pass a single fruit name at a time. But not able to pass more than one value. I did a bit research and found it's problem with Sybase. It cannot take multiple value.

I believe someone might have found a work around. Just need to get it working.

Thanks In Advance.!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create a comma separated string from the list using join in a expression:

```
strFruits= Join(Parameters!fruits.Value,",")
```

then your where clause would look like:

```
WHERE CHARINDEX(',' + COLUMN2 + ',' , ',' + @strFruits + ',')>0
```

the ',' added at the beginning and end of the strings are to make sure the search string is found even if it is located at beginning or end of the comma separated list.